# Some way to click a rescued Element of Javafx?

Tags: button, javafx, webview, click, webengine

I am trying to click a button with no id, only class. Because of that, I have had to recue the element by xpath, having an Element object, which no click method.
Does anyone know some strategy to achive clicking this Element?

Here the code where I am getting the Element:

```
WebView wv = new WebView();
WebEngine we = wv.getEngine();
we.load("https://www.milanuncios.com/");

we.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldState, newState) -> {
    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        Document doc = we.getDocument();
        Element inputField = null;
        try {
            inputField =
                    (Element) XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate("//*[@class=\"ma-NavigationTopNav-mainActions-desktop\"]",
                            doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (inputField != null) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "DENTRO "+inputField);
        }
    }
});
processPaneField.getChildren().add(wv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved with js script:

```
we.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('ma-NavigationTopNav-mainActions-desktop')[0].click()");
```